# Future run only part of code in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have question about [`future()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html), [`doFuture()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doFuture/index.html) usage.

I want to run `N` computations in parallel (using `foreach ... %dopar%`) - `N` is number of cores I have on my machine. To do so I use `future`:

```
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)

foreach(i = seq_len(N)) %dopar% {
    foo <- rnorm(1e6)
}
```

This works like a charm as I run `N` computations in parallel. But I need to implement another analysis step that uses high number of cores (eg., `N`). This is how code looks like:

```
foreach(i = seq_len(N)) %dopar% {
    foo <- rnorm(1e6)
    write.table(foo, paste0("file_", i, ".txt"))
    # This step uses high number of cores 
    system(paste0("head ", "file_", i, ".txt", " > ", "file_head_", i, ".txt")
}
```

I'm running multiple `rnorm` and `head` in parallel, but as `head` uses high number of cores (lets assume this) my analysis gets stuck.

**Question:**

How to run only part of code in parallel using `future`? (How to run only `rnorm` in parallel and then `head` sequential)? Is there any solution without using another loop for this? Or maybe I should switch to `doSNOW` or `parallel`?

**PS:**

My real code looks more like this:

```
library(doFuture)
library(dplyr)
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)

foreach(i = seq_len(N)) %dopar% {
    step1(i) %>%
        step2() %>%
        step3() %>%
        step4_RUN_SEQUENTIAL() %>% # I want to run this part not in parallel
        step5() # I want to run this part again in parallel
}
```

Response to [@Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602276/andrie) comment:

1. `future()` is my way to perform parallel computing in R. I'm new to it and find it easiest to use (compared to eg `parallel::mcapply`). However, if it's possible to do what I want in `doSNOW` or `parallel` then I'm more than happy to switch
2. I'm aware of that, but I'm looking for a solution with single loop

Comment: This isn't clear to me.  1) What role does `doFuture()` play, since you only use `foreach()`? 2)  Why don't you simply do `foreach() %dopar% step_1_to_3()` followed by `step4()` and then again `foreach() %dopar% step_5()` ?

Comment: @Andrie I updated my question

Comment: OK, so it seems clear to me that `future` plays no role in your question, and quite possibly is simply confusing.  I suggest you simply use `doParallel` instead, and you'll find lots of examples using this.  (Specifically, you're not using any of the delayed computation offered by the `future` package`.)  Also, you say you don't want a second loop.  You don't say why not.  If the point of `step4` is to do something on the aggregated results of `step3`, then I don't see you having any choice.  But I may be missing something.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your problem is that `step4` is parallelized itself, so you run into a nested parallelization problem. If you are using all your cores for the doParallel loop, I don't see the point of parallelizing `step4` again. You won't get any speedup, since you are using all your resources already. So if you can control the number of cores for `step4`, reduce them to 1 so this task runs serially as all other tasks in the loop. If you can't control this for some reason, you need to use 2 loops as @Andrie suggests or free enough resources to allow `step4` to run in parallel

Comment: @FridolinLinder Ah, that makes sense.